# Get javascript fields with specific names in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have object with such fields:

```
{
   d_name: { field_name: true },
   d_date: { field_date: ISODate() },
   status: 'success'
}
```

I need to get fields starting with `d_` and then push them to one array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to get fields...

Do you mean you need to get the keys? If so:

```
var d_keys = Object.keys(obj).filter(function (key) {
    return !key.indexOf("d_");
});
```

If you actually want the values:

```
var d_values = Object.keys(obj).filter(function (key) {
    return !key.indexOf("d_");
}).map(function (key) {
    return obj[key];
});
```

Note that this uses various ES5 methods ([`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)), so depending on your environment you may need appropriate shims.

Here are [working examples](http://jsfiddle.net/AesS8/) of both snippets.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the keys of the object, then compare the start of the key name:

```
var myObj = {
   d_name: { field_name: true },
   d_date: { field_date: ISODate() },
   status: 'success'
};
var outArray = {};
for(var key in myObj) {
  if(key.length >= 2 && key.substr(0,2) == "d_") {
    outArray[key] = myObj[key];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/93qjS/1/) is the fiddle hope it helps you

```
 var q = [];
for(k in s)
{
 if(k.indexOf("d_") == 0){
 q.push(s[k]);
}
```

Comment: `String.prototype.startsWith` is part of the ES6 proposal. It's not available in many environments. In Chrome Canary your fiddle throws a `TypeError`.